# How can I dismiss a View Controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I am pushing a controller via:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController"     bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Once there, I cannot go back with either

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

or

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

what should I use to dismiss the last view ?

Comment: You want to dismiss the first view only ??? is it ???

Comment: Question is incomplete.

Comment: Why you want to go beyond `self.window.rootViewController`; There is nothing there.

Comment: I am in fact in a Table View listing contacts. One I select one of the contacts, I go to a secondary TableView listing all conversations for the selected contact (with the above code). Once I am done, I want to go back to the first Tableview of contacts.

Answer (score 1):

To where you want to dismiss and go to?

This is the root view controller right? It cannot be "dismissed".
If you have a another view controller and this VC is pushed or modally presented from the second VC it can be dismissed

Window is the base canvas and VC's are added over it and shown.

Ok from your clarification you have an initial VC with contacts and you are trying to go to next page(DetailsVC) from that contactVC and then dismiss back from there.

What you currently doing is getting the window and making your detailVC as the root VC.This way you cannot dismiss to the contacts VC.Make an instance of the `detail VC` in the `didselectRowAtIndexpath` method of `contactsVC` and push it using navigation controller.

Then you can pop using the method `popViewControllerAnimated:`

This is an excellent [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies/) for you to start on

Comment: Like I said beofre, I am in fact in a Table View listing contacts. One I select one of the contacts, I go to a secondary TableView listing all conversations for the selected contact (with the above code). Once I am done, I want to go back to the first Tableview of contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not "pushing a controller". That code is essentially what you may find in your app delegate for setting up your one initial window and view.

Calling popViewController only works after you've pushed a controller onto that same navigation controller using pushViewController, which you haven't done.

Calling dismissViewController only works after you've presented a view controller with presentViewController, which again you haven't done.

Comment: This is something that could be in the  delegate but is in a standard class. I am in fact in a Table View listing contacts. One I select one of the contacts, I go to a secondary TableView listing all conversations for the selected contact (with the above code). Once I am done, I want to go back to the first Tableview of contacts. I understand what you say and that's why I am asking how to get back from this controller, since like you say, both previous cases are not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

I finally left the above technique and went for the traditional:

```
ViewController *detailViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```